# Reason for Development Directly on a Server

Tags: 2013, development, visual-studio-2015

Based on the answer I received [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165318/setting-up-a-development-environment), I was wondering why Microsoft insists on having Visual Studio installed directly on a SharePoint server.

Why can't they allow a remote connection to an on-premise SharePoint server?

Similar products like Dynamics CRM don't appear to have this restriction. I am just interested in the design/technical decision that has been taken here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using server side object model then you need to have Visual studio installed on the same machine as sharepoint. But if you are developing sharepoint solutions using CSOM (Client side object model) C#/JS then you can connect to SharePoint remotely. Code examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx).